# CSS and jQuery Analog clock - smooth animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having i minor problem with my CSS3/jQuery analog clock.

For every step, the clock-hands make, it is very hard. Instead I want the movement/animation to be smooth. I've already tried to use the `transition: all .1s` but it mess up, when the clock hands, reach the top.

I'm using `transform: rotate()` to rotate every hands. For every movement, it rotates 6 deg.

Maybe the solution could be, that instead of just rotate the hands, 6 deg for every second, minute and hour, it rotates 1 deg for every 1/6 of a second for the second-hand, every 10 seconds for the minute-hand and every 10 minutes for the hour-hand. I think it could create a more smooth hand-animation, but I do not know how to do this.

### This is my JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {

      setInterval( function() {
      var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
      var sdegree = seconds * 6;
      var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";

      $("#sec").css({ "transform": srotate });

      }, 1000 );

      setInterval( function() {
      var hours = new Date().getHours();
      var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
      var hdegree = hours * 30 + (mins / 2);
      var hrotate = "rotate(" + hdegree + "deg)";

      $("#hour").css({ "transform": hrotate});

      }, 1000 );

      setInterval( function() {
      var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
      var mdegree = mins * 6;
      var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";

      $("#min").css({"transform" : mrotate });

      }, 1000 );

});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FHNJf/1/)

Hope you understand the question, and can help me :)

Comment: "Maybe the solution could be ...", have you tried that solution you proposed yet before asking us? If that didn't work, what problems did you encounter with it?

Answer (score 3):

Set a *linear* transition for the hands:

```
#clock div {
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

To avoid the weird behaviour where the hands reverse to get to zero you should change your JS to work in milliseconds. This way the rotation value (degrees) only ever increments. CSS rotation is fine with that:

```
$(function() { 
     var i=0;
    setInterval( function() {
        //get time since midnight in milliseconds
         var now = new Date(),
        then = new Date(
        now.getFullYear(),
        now.getMonth(),
        now.getDate(),
        0,0,0),
        mil = now.getTime() - then.getTime(); // difference in milliseconds

          var h = (mil/(1000*60*60));
          var m = (h*60);
          var s = (m*60);
          //console.log(h+":"+m+":"+s);   


      var sdegree = (s * 6);
      var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";  
      $("#sec").css({ "transform": srotate });

      var hdegree = h * 30 + (h / 2);
      var hrotate = "rotate(" + hdegree + "deg)";
      $("#hour").css({ "transform": hrotate});

      var mdegree = m * 6;
      var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";      
      $("#min").css({ "transform" : mrotate });

         if(i>0){
             $("#clock").addClass("transform");       
         }
         i++;

      }, 1000 );

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FHNJf/10/

**UPDATE:**

Here's a pure JS solution for smooth sweeping hands. It uses [requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) for timing the loop, and because it doesn't use CSS transitions it doesn't suffer that weird behaviour where the hands have to 'catch up' when you return focus to the browser tab.

```
//use requestAnimationFrame for smoothness (shimmed with setTimeout fallback)
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
              window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

//initialize the clock in a self-invoking function
(function clock(){ 
    var hour = document.getElementById("hour"),
        min = document.getElementById("min"),
        sec = document.getElementById("sec");
    //set up a loop
    (function loop(){
        requestAnimFrame(loop);
        draw();
    })();
    //position the hands
    function draw(){
        var now = new Date(),//now
            then = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),0,0,0),//midnight
            diffInMil = (now.getTime() - then.getTime()),// difference in milliseconds
            h = (diffInMil/(1000*60*60)),//hours
            m = (h*60),//minutes
            s = (m*60);//seconds
        //rotate the hands accordingly
        sec.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + (s * 6) + "deg)";
        hour.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + (h * 30 + (h / 2)) + "deg)";
        min.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + (m * 6) + "deg)";
    } 
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FHNJf/13/

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to specify the transition duration on the hand elements. Try this:

```
#clock div {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.0s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1.0s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1.0s;
    transition-duration: 1.0s;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FHNJf/3/)

Comment: The only problem with this is, that when the hands are reaching 12 (the top), they quickly spins the other way around, and then starting over.

Answer (score 0):

You want the second (and all other) hands to move smoothly? Try adding the following css to the #sec div:

```
[prefix-]transition: all 1.00s linear 0.0s;
```

This will only get you part of the way there, you are going to have to be smart about how you tell the transform to rotate as it might end up causing bugs around the 12oclock mark.

For what its worth, you could probably have a single `setInterval(...)` which creates a single  `new Date()` and updates the hands accordingly.